# MySQL Performance - How to accelerate query for Build-Up / Burn-Down Chart?

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I am working on an application generate buildup and a burndown chart in MySQL/PHP which I use to generate using NVD3.js

My code below loops for every day for the min to max date of my dataset which can be filtered.

So far, I run the query 1 time for every day, which I realize can add a tremendous amount of delay, about 10 seconds to wait to load.

**How can I generate this data more quickly?**

**Invoking Code**

```
public function burnupAction()
    {
        $actionItemTable = $this->getActionItemTable();
        $burnUp =  array('TotalActionItems' => $actionItemTable->getBurnup('AssignedDate'),
                         'ECDItems' => $actionItemTable->getBurnup('ECD'),
                         'OriginalDueItems' => $actionItemTable->getBurnup('DueDate'),
                         'ActualOpenItems' => $actionItemTable->getBurnup('ClosedDate'));
        $this->response->setContent(json_encode($burnUp));
        return $this->response;
    }
```

**Build Up Chart Code**

```
for ($y = $minYear; $y <= $maxYear; $y++)
{
        if ($y == $minYear)
            $startMonth = $minMonth;
        else
            $startMonth = 1;

        if ($y == $maxYear)
            $finishMonth = $maxMonth;
        else
            $finishMonth = 12;


        for ($m = $startMonth; $m <= $finishMonth; $m++)
        {                       
            if ($m < 10)
            {
                $month = "0$m";
            }
            else 
            {
                $month = "$m";
            }
            $monthStr = $this->getMonth($m);


            for ($d = 1; $d <= 31; $d++)
            {
                    if ($d< 10)
                    {
                        $day = "0$d";
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        $day = "$d";
                    }

                    $dt = "$monthStr $day $y";
                    $start = "$y-$month-$day";
                    $end = "$y-$month-$day";

                    $where = $this->filterString();
                    $filtered = "SELECT * FROM actionitems " . $where;

                    if ($field == 'AssignedDate')
                    {
                        array_push($subsel, "(select '$dt' as AssignedDate, sum(case when AssignedDate Between '$start' and '$end' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NumActionItems' from ($filtered) s)");
                    }
                    if ($field == 'ECD')
                    {
                        array_push($subsel, "(select '$dt' as ECD, sum(case when ECD Between '$start' and '$end' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NumActionItems' from ($filtered) s)");
                    }
                    if ($field == 'DueDate')
                    {
                        array_push($subsel, "(select '$dt' as DueDate, sum(case when DueDate Between '$start' and '$end' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NumActionItems' from ($filtered) s)");
                    }
                    if ($field == 'ClosedDate')
                    {
                        array_push($subsel, "(select '$dt' as ClosedDate, sum(case when ClosedDate Between '$start' and '$end' then 1 else 0 end) as 'NumActionItems' from  ($filtered) s)");
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    if (count($subsel) == 0)
        return array();


    $sub = join(" union all ", $subsel);

    if ($field == 'AssignedDate')
    {
        $sql = "select AssignedDate, (@csum:= @csum + NumActionItems) as TotalActionItems from ($sub) t";
    }
    if ($field == 'ECD')
    {
        $sql = "select ECD, NumActionItems as ECDItems, (@csum:= @csum + NumActionItems) as TotalActionItems from ($sub) t";
    }
    if ($field == 'DueDate')
    {
        $sql = "select DueDate, NumActionItems as OriginalDueItems, (@csum:= @csum + NumActionItems) as TotalActionItems from ($sub) t";
    }
    if ($field == 'ClosedDate')
    {
        $sql = "select ClosedDate, NumActionItems as AcutalClosedItems, (@csum:= @csum + NumActionItems) as TotalActionItems from ($sub) t";
    }
```

**Generated Carts (Buildup on top / Burndown on bottom)**

[image: Buildup/Burdown Charts]

Comment: I assume you have indexes in place for the dates? What you could do is store the @csum values. Also can you list 1 or 2 complete queries in SQL. I see what your code does, but generating it in my head is not optimal to give a recommendation regarding performance.

Comment: Please see following - https://jsfiddle.net/06y6bz71/

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply, I believe I have not yet setup indexes for my query but if that should help I can accelerate it by adding it in.

Comment: Ok, I see what you did. Yes, this can be done quicker. Indexes will be 1 part, and the other part is the main query. I am going to use an answer box to get through this one: Feel free to comment on it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main part of your query is this:

```
SELECT 'Mar 01 2015' AS AssignedDate,
            Sum(CASE
                  WHEN assigneddate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-01'
                THEN 1
                  ELSE 0
                end)      AS 'NumActionItems'
     FROM   (SELECT *
             FROM   actionitems) s;
```

This query has 1 drawback: Per date the table actionitems is scanned.

To improve this the query can be written as:

```
SELECT 'Mar 01 2015' AS AssignedDate,
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumActionItems'
     FROM actionitems
     WHERE assigneddate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-01';
```

This is still not pretty, so a next step is required:
An alternative for all dates could be:

```
SELECT assigneddate,
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumActionItems'
     FROM actionitems
     WHERE assigneddate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-30'
     GROUP BY assigndate;
```

This would give you the 'NumActionItems' per date.

Adding your @csum as outer query:

```
SELECT assigneddate,
   ( @csum := @csum + numactionitems ) AS TotalActionItems 
FROM (    SELECT assigneddate,
            COUNT(*) AS 'NumActionItems'
     FROM actionitems
     WHERE assigneddate BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND '2015-03-30'
     GROUP BY assigndate) a
```

Should give the same result.

Also add the index:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_ai_nn_1 ON actionitems(assigneddate);
```

This index will work if your date range you are scanning the table for is << smaller then the number of rows you are selecting.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.  Let make the changes, and I will report back.  Also, my row count is actually the opposite, it is much less than the number of dates I produce.

Comment: Ok, 1 hint: This does not return data for dates which do not have data in the database. So when iterating over this set, take that into account. 
Also first check your query results and these in a mysql session: Saves you a lot of time if there is a mistake in this one :)

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I am trying to make it produce all dates without any value, which I think might necessitate keeping my main loops in my code.